# Rewrite a ruby class on the fly

Tags: ruby, highline

I'm using HighLine to write my console application and I would like to modify the HighLine::Question::in_range! function so that tab completion stayed activated but that highline do not bother checking if the words typed are in the range.

So let's say I have a tab completion list like %w{app1, app2, app3}

I'd like to be able to do that in my console:

app1 -option1 value1 -option2 value2

From what I understand from the code in HighLine it appears that I would need to pass the in_range! check, so that function needs to return true.

I don't want to modify to code source HighLine directly in its file obviously. So I'm looking for a solution to be able to modify or rewrite that function on the fly in my own code. Is there a solution to do what I'm looking for?

Thanks for your time and I hope I've asked my question clearly enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to modify the `in_range?` method for a particular `Question` object `x`, you can do

```
class << x
  def in_range?
    true
  end
end
```

If you want to modify it for *all* `Question` objects:

```
class Question
  def in_range?
    true
  end
end
```

However, I wonder if you really need to do that in your case. I think you can simply set `above`, `below` and `in` to `nil` in your question to trivialize the `in_range?` check.